# Developing iOS apps with Flash Builder 4.5 under Windows

Tags: xcode, ios, flash-builder

I just upgraded to Flash Builder 4.5, and I am trying to decide whether to install the Win or OS X version, since Adobe only allows you to install on one platform. I have been, up until now, developing an AS3 application using FB 4 under Windows 7 on my MacBook, and my Production Premium CS5 license is also for Windows (and I also do C++/Visual Studio development as well). Now I am going to try the iPhone Packager, to port my app to iOS. It seems to me that the workflow will be awkward once I cross-compile to Objective-C - as I will need to either reboot into OS X to compile and debug, or I will need to run FB 4.5 in a parallels session under OS X (though Adobe's activation freaked out when I tried this with Prod Prem CS4). The FB 4.5 / iOS workflow still requires xCode does it not? Is it foolish to even try this? Should I just bite the bullet and switch over to working in OSX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's better to keep things simple and stick with OSX. Constant switching among platforms is a sure productivity killer. Bite the bullet and stay on OSX - it will pay off on the mid run.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing all of this in OSX